# 2-3 и 2-3-4 деревья

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Доброго времени суток!

2-3 и 2-3-4 деревья. В каких случаях следует использовать каждое из них? В чем первое кардинально лучше второго, и наоборот? Почему получили распространение именно такие конфигурации, а не 4-5-6 деревья?